# onLongPress not working as expected

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am having a surfaceview on which gesture detection is implemented using following code.

```
surfaceview.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this ) {

    });


  public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx) {
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"On Down press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;



            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.d("g","g");


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"On long press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("h","h");



        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1,
                float arg2, float arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"On Show press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg0) {

            return true;
        }
    }


}
```

I want to do an action after user touches screen and holds there for some time. I think such action should go inside `onLongPress` method. However the toast inside the method is initiated when user presses long after first tap i.e. on second tap. Is this how this method is supposed to work or I am making some mistake   ?

Comment: Im not that sure but I believe the problem comes from the onDown that blocks the code there since a longpress is also a keydown... I see that you have a onSingleTapUp, I would try use that instead

Comment: I amalready doing something on single tap.

Comment: Remove the whole onDown and try the code again

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: try returning false i onDown