# OnLongPress is not working with our touch events

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, touch-event

I am developing a game in which I want to perform certain operations when user single touch the screen, and some other operations when user long press the screen. For this, I have created a Gesture Detector class and add events to them.

Surface View Class

```
public MySurfaceView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs):base(context, attrs)
    {
        this.context=context;
        SetWillNotDraw(false);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());

    }

 public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        Log.Debug(Tag, "Inside" + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + "Method");
        return gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e); 
    }
```

Gesture Listener Class

```
  private class GestureListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
    {
        public override bool OnDown(MotionEvent e)
        {
            Log.Debug("Tag", "Inside Gesture OnDown Event");
            // don't return false here or else none of the other 
            // gestures will work
            return true;

        }

        public override bool OnSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e)
        {
            Log.Debug("Tag", "Inside Gesture OnSingleTapConfirmed Event");

            return true;
        }

        public override bool OnDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)
        {
            Log.Debug("Tag", "Inside Gesture OnDoubleTap Event");
            return true;
        }

        public override void OnLongPress(MotionEvent e)
        {
            Log.Debug("Tag", "Inside Long Press Event");
        }




    }
```

All events except OnLongPress is working with the above code. After going through the comments of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252675/onlongpress-not-working-as-expected). I have to return false for OnDown event. After updating my code base on the comment my OnLongPress event start working but now only OnLongPress event is working.

```
   public override bool OnDown(MotionEvent e)
        {
            Log.Debug("Tag", "Inside Gesture OnDown Event");
            // don't return false here or else none of the other 
            // gestures will work
            return false;

        }
```

Is there any way by which I can make OnLongPress work with other events as I need all the events to work together.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your `OnTouchEvent` to the following:

```
 public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e){
     Log.Debug(Tag, "Inside" + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + "Method");
     gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e); 
     return true;
}
```

You can find the explanation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector#detect-a-subset-of-supported-gestures).

Comment: It worked but only for first time, after that it is taking long press event as single touch confirmed event. Any suggestions.